# css div table row border fade

Tags: html, css

Is there a way for a div using `display: table` to have a row border that fades?

Here's the [fiddle of the table](http://jsfiddle.net/v98ffkf4/) that needs to have row bottom border like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/41ectto5/) instead.

Comment: @alex if the table is responsive adding `border-image` to emulate that effect won't work well

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v98ffkf4/4/?

Comment: @alex ah ok, my bad, wasn't aware you could do that using border-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the border rule you have, and add these two rules:

```
div.div-row:after{
    content:"";
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 90%);
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    margin-top:46px;
  /* W3C */
}
div.div-heading:after{
    content:"";
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 90%);
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    margin-top:36px;
  /* W3C */
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v98ffkf4/4/)**